# Why did doctrine create 2 queries when I use findOneByProperty() method?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a curiosity about doctrine2. Why did doctrine create 2 queries when I use `findOneByProperty (__call)`?

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->findOneByName($user->getName());
```

Symfony web profiler say that there are 2 queries to bd, why does it happen???

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSPEL.png

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because `$user->getName()` itself triggers a query! If you get rid of it and pass a string value as name e.g. 'Name4', Doctrine will run a single query instead.

Another thing is, you already seem to know the `$user` object so why would you run another query to get same object again!?

**Update:**

This is technically what you're doing:

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $result1 = $this->userRepository->findOneByName('Name4');
    $result2 = $this->userRepository->findOneByName($result1->getName());

    return $this->getTemplate(['result' => $result2]);
}
```

But you should do this instead:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $result1 = $this->userRepository->findOneByName('Name4');

    return $this->getTemplate(['result' => $result1]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, I use type hinting, my controller(Symfony) is this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user-{name}", name="queryUsers")
 */
public function queryUsersAction(User $user)
{
   $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->findOneByName($user->getName());

   return $this->render('query/query-by-property.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user
   ));
}
```

Comment: This is what you should do: `@Route("/user/{name}", name="query_users")` and `queryUsersAction($name)` then `findOneByName($name)`